# Read file from TFS and use it to upload in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, tfs, azure-pipelines

I have scenario to upload excel file. I copied that file to my solution and using below code to get the file path and I am able to upload when I run it locally. The issue is when I try to execute the test case once the build is completed I am getting an error as it is unable to fine the file path.

```
string fileLocation = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).Parent.Parent.FullName);
fileLocation = fileLocation + "\\BDD.Automation.files\\TestData\\testfile.xlsm";
```

Comment: You should use [Directory.Exists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) before trying to move files.

Comment: I tried to implement below code was getting error.

Comment: did you check whether `fileLocation` exists ?

Comment: please also include the error that is displayed to you. Is your error an `FileNotFoundException` ?

Comment: Hi Felix, Directory.GetParent() method is able to read file path but Directory.exists()  returns false also the fileLocation is exists.

Comment: the above code is working even from other machine locally after a check-in, but failing when it is running as part CI. please let me know some inputs on this.

Comment: You Need to include the error message! We cant guess what the problem is...

Comment: Did you tfs build got passed , if failed which step failed? Please share the related build log error. Better to enable VERBOSE  mode log, by setting `system.debug=true` http://blog.devmatter.com/enabling-verbose-output-in-team-foundation-build-logs/

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell you that this is a selenium test case am using Autoit as a nuget package and executing my test case. My build is success and not getting any error. When I execute it using browser stack, the steps till browse for file is successful but it is not able to locate excel file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your quick support. I found solution for this issue. The above piece of code is working fine. The issue was with IWebDriver as it does not support file upload in browserstack. Used RemoteWebDriver for this requirement and it is working like a charm.